# awk errors in file parsers

Tags: bash, awk

Im trying to parse and insert elements of a file using awk.

```
clear

MESSAGE=$(cat emailTranscript.txt)

awk -F READLINE="$MESSAGE" 'BEGIN{
FS=","}
{
    CURRENTMESSAGE=READLINE
    gsub("#FIRSTNAME", $1, CURRENTMESSAGE)
    gsub("#LASTNAME", $2, CURRENTMESSAGE)
    gsub("#MAJOR", $3, CURRENTMESSAGE)
    gsub("#ADDRESS", $4, CURRENTMESSAGE)

    print CURRENTMESSAGE "\n--------------------------\n s"
}' nameAddresses.csv
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm handling my csv file?

Comment: Can you show the sample content of both the files being used here?

Comment: No exaggeration - literally every line of your script is wrong so it's not a good starting point for us to help you. post some sample input, expected output, and tell us what you're trying to do and we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say precisely what you're trying to do, but I can say with a great deal of confidence you are doing it wrong. From your code, I'll guess that `emailTranscript.txt` contains a form letter and `nameAddresses.csv` contains the data to be substituted in.

The biggest error, and the one I suspect is your problem, is that `-F` specifies the field separator.  You want `-v`, to set a variable.